# Rail to Rail op Amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

EL_IN signal varies from 0-12V. The output ADC_EL is going to controllers ADC with 0-3V range.

[image]

Can someone please explain this circuit & if this circuit is correct or not?
Should the EL_IN be connected to inverting or non-inverting terminal?

Comment: If you're wanting a voltage follower, feed the output back to the inverting terminal.

Comment: If you want your output voltage to be 1/4, you want a 3:1 ratio in R89 to R90

Comment: positive loopback aren't admitted. You do amplify and bring back the signal all the time, this goes out of bounds. Swap the +/- inputs.

Comment: As a rule of thumb "feedback goes to the negative terminal"

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a divider with a voltage follower. The inverting and non-inverting inputs need to be swapped.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKft5k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Passive 4:1 voltage divider.*

The circuit of Figure 1 should do the trick for you.

- R1,2 and 3 can be replaced by any combination of resistors to give you three times the value of R4.
- R4 needs to be a factor of ten lower than the input impedence of your 0 - 3 V ADC so that the ADC doesn't load the divider too much.